# How to select the Checked rows in GridviewRow and display it in next page in VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am trying to get the rows from the gridviewrow and display it in the detail view in next page. I am using Asp.net with VB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply iterate the collection and check the status. You can then put the selected rows into a session object or something else to pass on to the next page.

```
For Each Row As GridViewRow In MyGrid.Rows

   Dim SelectCheck As CheckBox = DirectCast(Row.FindControl("chkSelectForDetail"), CheckBox)

   If SelectCheck.Checked
      ' Add your logic here to save the data or passing on to the detail page.    
   End If

Next
```

Comment: can you show me how do I save my data as an array list and display it.

Comment: There are lots of options, it depends on your scenario. If you're working with records from a database, you can save the Ids from all the selected rows into an array and store that in the session. Then on the Page_Load even of your details page, you retrieve that list, and use it as a query to get the records you need. There's no one way to do things at that point and you'll want to find what will work best for your situation.